# Bash Bad Substitution Error: Trying to Execute Python Script

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm following the tutorial here to convert MacJournal journal entries to DayOne journal entries: https://basilsalad.com/how-to/migrate-mac-journal-day-one/

And I am having issues on the very last part.

I moved my MacJournal exported text file to the same directory as `MacJournalToDayOne.py` so in terminal, when I run the command "ls" it lists the python file and the MacJournal file which is "dreams.txt" in the same directory.

Everything works fine up until this part here:

```
./MacJournalToDayOne.py "${export-file}" --journal="${journal-name}"
```

When I add in the file names and the journal I want to import into, I run it as:

```
./MacJournalToDayOne.py "${dreams.txt}" --journal="${MJImport}"
```

Which gives the error: `-bash: ${dreams.txt}: bad substitution`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably is supposed to be `./MacJournalToDayOne.py dreams.txt --journal=MJImport`

Comment: No dots are allowed in variable names when you use `bash`.

Comment: The page says "replace ${export-file} with name of the file that was exported from MacJournal and ${journal-name} with the name of the journal in Day One." Instead of replacing `${export-file}`, you just replaced `export-file`, leaving the `${` and `}` in place. You have to follow the instructions exactly.